# Listener and Performance

Tags: java, performance, listener, jira

I have a question about the listener and performance.
For example:
I have 5 class:
+ Add Attachment Listener
+ Priority Field Change Listener
+ Add Comment Listener
+ Change Status of Issue Listener
+ Change Assignee Listener
All of the class will listen on

```
@EventListener
  public void onIssueEvent(IssueEvent issueEvent) {
// Do some thing
}
```

I have 2 way implemented for this problem
Option 1:
I register 5 class like this:

```
eventPublisher.register(AddAttachmentListener.class);
eventPublisher.register(PriorityFieldChangeListener.class);
eventPublisher.register(AddCommentListener.class);
eventPublisher.register(ChangeStatusOfIssueListener.class);
eventPublisher.register(ChangeAssigneeListener.class);
```

And use in side each class funtion onIssueEvent()

Option 2:
I just register only one class:

```
eventPublisher.register(IssueEventListener.class);
```

And in the function onIssueEvent() I will switch to each event.

But, If I register 5 class it will make the code cleaner and easy for reading.

So, which option could I follow?
If I use option 1, will I affect the performance?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Nice Question. Agreed 5 separate class will make more cleaner. but this decision you can take only base on your future requirement. if there is requirement to adding more events of business logic for events then take the option 1 if there is chances for limited events or business logic then go with option 2 .

By adding the clean and proper commenting in option 2 also you can manage clean coding.

Go with option 1 for big application and 2 for small application. Kind of micro services makes application clean and loosely coupled.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep it simpler by using a single listener. Chances are, you want to listen to all five events elsewhere, too, and always creating five classes doesn't make it cleaner. Chances are, you add a sixth listener....

While switching on the event kind might be frowned upon, it itself doesn't make your code any worse. Just keep the switching method small by using other method for the fixe cases. This also makes it simpler in case you change your mind later.